# List related tags for blog posts stored in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to figure out how I can get a list of related tags from blog posts stored in MongoDB.

**Data Structure**

```
{
    title: "Post #1",
    tags: { "news", "politics" }
},
{
    title: "Post #2",
    tags: { "news", "entertainment" }
},
{
    title: "Post #3",
    tags: { "entertainment", "music", "theatre" }
},
{
    title: "Post #4",
    tags: { "entertainment", "music", "concerts" }
}
```

**Desired Result**

If I want to get a list of tags related to "entertainment", it queries the posts to find similar tags. Similar tags are the ones that are also used when a post is tagged "entertainment".

I'd like to be able to get the following result:

```
Tag       Count
========  ======
music     2    (because there are 2 posts tagged with music + entertainment)
concert   1
theatre   1
news      1
```

Is there a way to get it as close to that as possible? The closest I've been able to get is to use `db.posts.find({tags: "entertainment"});` and then loop through and construct those values outside of MongoDb. I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the work to the write side to maintain fast reads. Lets say you are trying to add `new_tag` to a post that already has `some_list_of_tags`. The following code would build a collection with the desired values:

```
for old_tag in some_list_of_tags:
    db.related_tags.update({'_id':new_tag}, {'$inc':{'counts.'+old_tag:1}}, upsert=True)
    db.related_tags.update({'_id':old_tag}, {'$inc':{'counts.'+new_tag:1}}, upsert=True)
```

Then to get the results for 'entertainment, just do:

```
db.related_tags.find({'_id': 'entertainment'})
```

You can use the [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command to atomically add a tag to a post and fetch all existing tags:

```
old_tags = db.posts.findAndModify({query: {_id: ID},
                                   update: {$addToSet: {tags: new_tag}},
                                   fields: {tags: 1}
                                  })['tags']
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that option. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find one. MongoDB has very limited (but very efficient) query capabilities. For something like you would need map/reduce but as MongoDB M/R today is single threaded and it's JS engine is not the fastest you might end up with having the best solution already.